# Error: invalid subscript type 'list' in R

Tags: r

Having an issue here - I'm creating a function using the eclipse parameter to deal with a varying function parameters. I recreated as similar situation to show the issue I keep bumping into,

```
> d <- data.frame(alpha=1:3, beta=4:6, gamma=7:9)
> d
  alpha beta gamma
1     1    4     7
2     2    5     8
3     3    6     9

> x <- list("alpha", "beta")
> rowSums(d[,c(x)])
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How do I deal with the issue of feeding a list into a subset call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We need to use concatenate to create a `vector` instead of `list`

```
x <- c("alpha", "beta")
rowSums(d[x])
#[1] 5 7 9
```

and if we are using `list`, then `unlist` it to create a `vector` as `data.frame` takes a `vector` of column names (column index) or row names (row index) to subset the columns or rows

```
x <- list("alpha", "beta")
rowSums(d[unlist(x)])
#[1] 5 7 9
```

Comment: @S31 I would guess, you are using `d[,x]` instead use `d[x]` as the former returns a vector when there is only a single column unless you specify `d[,x, drop = FALSE]`